# Structuring Components in Angular

Tags: angular9

I am new to Angular and I have a question.

When creating a page which utilises smooth scrolling to capture sections from nav, what would your advice be? Would it be to have each section as separate components? If so why would that be the case and if not what would be an ideal way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically yes but not necessarily. Because if the component can be reused in multiple places,should always create a separate reusable components.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shehan, I do understand but say I have different sections in the home page which have the same css but different content, for example

Home Section
About us Section 
Contact Us Section

All defined in the home page. Would I need to split them all into separate components or would I have a component called sections and the content project into that component what I want the user to see? it's been a head scratcher for me.

Thanks

Comment: If you're considering breaking apart into multiple components, a good question to ask is whether there will ever be a situation in your app where those new components exist apart from each other. If you see potential for reuse then you should go with reusable components. Considering your situation, You can have a single component and inject what you want while archiving single responsibility principle.